# scala list read value of given string

Tags: scala, scala-collections

first list

```
val l1 = List(("A",12,13),("B",122,123),("C",1212,123))
```

finding string

```
val l2 = "A"
```

If string `"A"` presents in list then display matching data in above case if string `"A"` match then output will be
`12`

else string does not match then shows only `0`

Answer (score 4):

Find first match; retrieve second part of tuplet or 0

```
 l1.find(_._1 == "A").map(_._2).getOrElse(0)
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a little nasty rule exists in scala pattern matching, if some variable starts with an Upper case letter the it matches against its value, so you can rename `val l2 = "A"` to `val L2 = "A"` the you the following would work -

```
scala> l1.collectFirst{ case (L2, i, _) => i }.getOrElse(0)
res0: Int = 12
```

Answer (score 0):

```
l1.find(_._1 == l2).map(_._2).getOrElse(0)
```

or more verbose version

```
l1.find(a => a._1 == l2).map(a => a._2).getOrElse(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

Using a for comprehension the solution may be reformulated as return second element in matching tuples or else and empty list if no matches were found, namely

```
for ( (s,i,j) <- l1 if s == l2) yield i
```

which delivers

```
List(12)
```